# remote work and mileage reimbursement

Tags: telecommute, remote-work, reimbursement

I interviewed for a position which is mostly remote work.
I live 2 hours away from the company site and I have a place to stay in between the site any my home whenever necessary.
I know I have to go onsite during the initial several days, so that's probably considered a regular commute.

After that, is all subsequent travel to the company site (e.g. once or twice a week, not necessarily every week) considered commuting or is it reasonable to request reimbursement??

This position pays much better than my current one and I just realized this about mileage etc., sigh. Current job is good about reimbursement though pay is not so good and it's not a great fit.

Comment: At the very least we need to know what country are we talking about here, and is this contracting or employment

Comment: Probably yes this is commuting. Whether you can get reimbursed depends entirely on the company.

Comment: What does your contract say where your place of work is? Getting there is on you. Sending you elsewhere is on them. At least in normal juristictions.

Comment: It is always reasonable to ask what company policy is.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR - Random strangers on internet cannot answer this, the best person to ask this question is the HR/Admin/Travel desk for your new company**.

**Usually**, any employment that is not full-time remote, does not consider commute to office in reimbursement category. Employee is suppose to arrange for the transport and the cost thereof.

However, since you mentioned "mostly-remote", there *might be* a provision to get reimbursed (or have company arranged or company provided transport facility), if you have to travel on work requirements - you'll get to know once you ask.

Bottom line: ask them, but be prepared to hear "no" as an answer, as that is the most likely outcome.

Comment: you’re right about the tl;dr, but people can give me general information about what to expect, which is better than nothing. :)

Comment: That is exactly what is written in the _longer_ part. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you are concerned with: will my company pay me for this driving/lodging; is there a tax implication.  The tax question 100% depends on the jurisdiction.

The reimbursement for these driving costs beck to the main office, and any lodging related to those trips, is negotiable. Many times it depends on the reason why the job is remote. If they are paying you to work in a particular city because they have many customers there and they want somebody close to them, the occasional trip to the main office is likely to be paid for by the company. If they would prefer you to be close to the main office, then they are less likely to pay for your driving and lodging.

The tax situation depends on why and which country. It can range from what they pay you is considered taxable income, to it not being taxable income. Some places may allow you to deduct these expenses.

Answer (score 0):

Most US companies will align with how the IRS deals with mileage.

Under the IRS scheme, your trips between home and office is not deductible.  Any trips from the office to carry out other work *are* deductible.  Companies will lean toward doing reimbursements for the latter situation because trips from office to clients can become a huge expense for employees to shoulder until tax season.

That said, I think you might want to consider that remote work is a benefit to you and not necessarily to the company.  **It can actually hurt your opportunity** if you start asking for other perks that they wouldn't give to an employee who drives in every day.

Proceed with caution.

Answer (score -1):

In my team there are people in 2 locations, about 1-1,5h drive apart. My colleagues who work not at the main office are expected to come to the main office maybe 1-3 days a month. When they do they get their mileage expenses paid for, I don't think they get money for meals and definitely not for lodging.

Depends really a lot on the location and the company itself, also the size of the company.

Comment: Not expecting anything for the lodging, just whatever consideration for the travel. Thank you, Tom